# C# batch up operations to load in remote database asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, data-synchronization

I have several front end web app servers, running ASP.NET MVC apps, which collect some analytics data on visitors.

I want to collect this data into a central database, via a Web API call.

I don't want to lose data, but I also don't want the front end servers to slow or stop in the event that the webapi/db server is not available.

I'm envisioning writing all these events to a log file and then run an async process to ship them to the central webapi/db, and can retry in case the server is not available for a time.

Is there some standard library or method for performing this, without building a bunch of custom code around it?

Comment: The classic approach to this would be to use a messaging system of some sort, like an SQS or Azure queue, or something like Kafka or Kinesis, to put the messages in and then process them asynchronously. What's your hosting environment, do you have any of those kinds of services available?

Comment: Any kind of queue will do, I often used RabbitMQ for this kind of things. Log file might be problematic because files are not designed to be modified concurrently.

Comment: do message queues depend on calling a remote api? I really want to cache the calls locally so there is no chance of remote server unavailability causing data loss.

Comment: One approach would be to trigger a new thread to do the logging and then just doing a try-catch where you log to the db server, and write to disk if it fails.
Just guessing that writing to files on the disk could be more expensive than calling an API, so it might not be worth the hassle to be writing to the disk all the time